# Object Morphing and Code Reuse

Tags: computer-science, code-reuse

Can anyone please explain what Object Morphing and Code Reuse are? Additionally, what are the applications of Object Morphing in Code Reuse? I don't need the answer for a specific language, rather, I need it in a generic sense! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you mean polymorphism and code reuse?

Comment: Well, I was asked to read up on Object Morphing and its Application in Code Reuse. Now I am totally lost and have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated, Leonardo!

Comment: Object morphing is not a common term. The only reference I found is an article about "class morphing":  http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-73589-2_19#page-1